# Sorting elements by value and removing duplicates

Tags: xslt, sorting, select

I have the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewTerms>
  <newTerm>XPath</newTerm>
  <newTerm>AutoValue</newTerm>
  <newTerm>XPath</newTerm>
  <newTerm>context</newTerm>
  <newTerm>AutoValue</newTerm>
  <newTerm>language files</newTerm>
   <newTerm>AutoValue</newTerm>
  <newTerm>.NET</newTerm>
  <newTerm>XPath</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

I want to sort it, and it functions perfectly with the following:

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">  
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is I am getting (Obviously) a sorted output list with the elements with same values in repetition (e.g XPath, AutoValue). I want to have the sorted list without the repeated values. That is, I want to have each value only once in the sorted XML output.

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kNewTermByValue" match="newTerm" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="NewTerms">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates
             select="newTerm[count(.|key('kNewTermByValue',.)[1])=1]">
                <xsl:sort/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<NewTerms xp_0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../XSD\CC-CustomDocuTags.xsd" xmlns:xp_0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <newTerm>.NET</newTerm>
    <newTerm>AutoValue</newTerm>
    <newTerm>context</newTerm>
    <newTerm>EPF</newTerm>
    <newTerm>language files</newTerm>
    <newTerm>XPath</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

**Note**: Do not sort attributes and children together because you can't output an attribute after you output a children.

Comment: +1 - Better answer. I think that the `count(.|key('keyName',.)[1])=1` method of testing for the first node in a set is much prettier than comparing IDs (even if I don't always use it).

Comment: @lwburk: I also like this because of Set Theory. But it only works when you are absolutely sure that both operands are singletons (no one is empty).

Comment: +1 wonderful, i'm learning a lot from you guys. it's a shame now, that my answer got accepted. is there a way to reconsider it (for all the others who are looking for such a solution to be pointed at this one)?

Comment: @rekaszeru: No problem. Besides the exponentially complex distinction method, the only real problem with your solution is that you sort together attributes and node children. I think you should amend that.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter your sort's select:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And it will give you the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewTerms>
    <newTerm>.NET</newTerm>
    <newTerm>AutoValue</newTerm>AutoValueAutoValue
    <newTerm>EPF</newTerm>
    <newTerm>XPath</newTerm>XPathXPath
    <newTerm>context</newTerm>
    <newTerm>language files</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

Comment: THANK You! I was trying to do it with the key() function ... and was reaching no where. I think it's mainly bcos I didn't actually get how the key() function works and reacts.

Comment: Note that this drops attributes. Also, I don't mind checking for siblings of the same type for small inputs; the performance difference won't be noticeable. But it's worth noting that using keys is the more idiomatic XSLT way to do this and can have serious performance benefits on large inputs. I think my policy will be to at least mention this when forgoing keys.